# flutterfire-web: How to upload large files to firebase storage in web based flutter app

Tags: flutter, web, firebase-storage, large-files

Apparently, the web implementation of FlutterFire storageref.putFile **does not support** the **dart:html File** object.

Because of this I cannot find a simple way to upload large files, since all the other options require to load the data into the browser first.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use putFile. Use putBlob. Here is the code.

```
html.FileUploadInputElement uploadInput = html.FileUploadInputElement();
uploadInput.click();

// Wait for the user to select a file
await uploadInput.onChange.first;

// Get the selected file
int size =
    uploadInput.files!.first.size;
html.Blob file = uploadInput
    .files!.first
    .slice(0, size - 1, '');
```

The slice function will not load the entire file in memory and hence it is safe to use for large files.

To upload the data to firebase use following code

```
Reference upload = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("<your_path>/test.csv");
UploadTask uploadTask = upload.putBlob(file);
```

Comment: Wow that's some really obscure and non-documented way to do it. Why would a slice of the complete file not even load the complete file? So many questions. I'll have to try it out first before I confirm that this actually works as expected.